# Handling lines with quotes using python's readline

Tags: python, readline

I've written a simple shell-like program that uses readline in order to provide smart completion of arguments. I would like the mechanism to support arguments that have spaces and are quoted to signify as one argument (as with providing the shell with such).

I've seen that shlex.split() knows how to parse quoted arguments, but in case a user wants to complete mid-typing it fails (for example: 'complete "Hello ' would cause an exception to be thrown when passed to shlex, because of unbalanced quotes).

Is there code for doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any existing code for the task, but if I were to do this I'd catch the exception, try adding a fake trailing quote, and see how shlex.split does with the string thus modified.

Comment: I've considered that, but wanted to see whether there's something less ugly. Because then you'd have to try for both add " or ', etc, and that just isn't... pretty :)

Comment: It isn't pretty because the use case seems rather complex.

Comment: Implemented like so today, for the lack of other options.

Comment: @abyx, yeah, a small inelegance is better than leaving a problem unsolved, I agree!

Answer (score 1):

GNU Readline allows for that scenario with the variable `rl_completer_quote_characters`.  Unfortunatelly, Python does not export that option on the standard library's `readline` module (even on 3.7.1, the latest as of this writing).

I found a way of doing that with `ctypes`, though:

```
import ctypes

libreadline = ctypes.CDLL ("libreadline.so.6")
rl_completer_quote_characters = ctypes.c_char_p.in_dll (
    libreadline, 
    "rl_completer_quote_characters"
)
rl_completer_quote_characters.value = '"'
```

Note this is clearly not portable (possibly even between Linux distros, as the libreadline version is hardcoded, but I didn't have plain `libreadline.so` on my computer), so you may have to adapt it for your environment.

Also, in my case, I set only double quotes as special for the completion feature, as that was my use case.

**References**

- https://robots.thoughtbot.com/tab-completion-in-gnu-readline#adding-quoting-support
- @eryksun's comment on [how to set data to a global variable in a shared library using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214677/how-to-set-data-to-a-global-variable-in-a-shared-library-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

To make @caxcaxcoatl answer a little bit more portable, readline hardcoded version can be replaces with `readline.__file__` and it will be:

```
import ctypes
import readline

libreadline = ctypes.CDLL (readline.__file__)
rl_completer_quote_characters = ctypes.c_char_p.in_dll (
    libreadline, 
    "rl_completer_quote_characters"
)
rl_completer_quote_characters.value = '"'
```